# SikaFix Foundation Kit -the instructional video shows that cement is applied to the crack prior to the epoxy reason-does it work?

Tags: repair, foundation, crack

I am referring to this video which is non-sense to me
The worker applied cement to kind of cover the crack but you see her pushing the cement into the crack
In particular if you have cinder blocks this is not going to work -the cement will close the crack at the surface of the wall
The resin is supposed to be injected into the wall and expanding into the crack but in case of a cinder block there is a huge cavity behind the wall of each block that the epoxy will never seal

Am I missing anything here ?

The video
https://youtu.be/urTPztDzpaE?t=208

Comment: I don’t think that kit will work for hollow block walls. I would contemplate filling the voids with regular low-expand foam, then maybe an epoxy or this kit on the crack.

Comment: this product is a fiasco in many ways

Comment: It’s a ton more work, but you might consider membranes on the outside.

Comment: This is a basement with above the grade windows, the crack is like 7" above the ground level under the window sill and then it goes down like 4', wider at the top, very thin and the bottom. Digging up that much is not excluded in the future if it is possible to patch that area only and not the entire wall. It gave me problems once in 10 years, that one time was when it rained like hell. I am renovating that room so I thought I would use the opportunity and  deal with this.